# Getting List of Open Events in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql

i have to retrieve list of Open Events in salesforce
i am using following method for getting list of open Events

```
public List<OpenActivity> getActivity1(){

Meeting_Master__c mmm= [SELECT (SELECT Subject,Location__c,EndDateTime,StartDateTime
                           FROM OpenActivities Where IsTask = false )
                   FROM Meeting_Master__c where Id =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
return mmm.openActivities;
}
```

ok i got the list but i need event's  StartDateTime field but it is an invalid field for OpenActivity please specify how to get list of OpenEvents in which StartDateTime is also included??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use query to event object

```
 [SELECT Subject, 
         Location__c,
         EndDateTime,
         StartDateTime
 FROM Event 
 WHERE  WhatId =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: can u please specify what is difference between event and open Event

Comment: The openActivity is object which is represent the both instances: events & tasks and in this context we can't to query specific event's fields. Also we can query openActivities only on nested query for target object, e.g. Account. Event & Task is also represent as a different objects and can be queried via SOQL.

Comment: then what is difference between openActivity and Activity??

Comment: OpenActivity is read-only object which represents open tasks and events associated with an object.                              

Regarding activity: In the user interface, task and Event records are collectively referred to as activities.